# Leaking from above

Tags: water, bathtub, leaking

I have a bathroom that is upstairs right above my kitchen.  Lately we have noticed a lot of water on the countertops and floor after we shower. I thought the drain was clogged so I purchased some drain cleaner and followed the directions.  This morning when I showered the water leaking was worse. The house was built in the 1980s all original plumbing.

What could be causing this leakage?

Comment: Get it inspected by a plumber. As it stands you question can only be answered by guesswork.

Comment: You have a leak.  Will need to remove ceiling and see what exactly is leaking, the drain pipes, shower floor, or less likely the water pipes(they are usually a constant leak).

Comment: It could be a cracked pipe, it could be a loose fitting. There are any numbers of causes for water leaks.

Comment: … and removing the drywall on the ceiling will be necessary anyway because it’s been soaked and is likely to grow mold…

Comment: The leak got worse when the drain cleaner ate the stuff that was partially plugging the holes. Cut a square out where the water is coming through if dripping you may want to poke a hole and catch the water that may be building up. If a section is not removed soon a very large section may give way and make a huge mess.